# Ajax add to cart working But Add to cart not working for configurable products

Tags: php, magento, soap

If we use "Ajax Add to cart " button, than we will get shipping charges for "configurable Products".

: [link1](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal.html)

but if we use normal Add to cart button we are not getting shipping charges : [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html)

we are using custom shipping method, so we are facing this problem :

ex: please use "560043" as zip code in cart page bottom, you can check shipping charges.

shipping charges related code : `app/code/local/extension/Mpperproductshipping/Model/Carrier/Localdelivery.php`

```
<?php
class Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    /*  Use group alias */
    protected $_code = 'mpperproductshipping';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){        
    $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();
    $restrictedCodes = array(

110001,
110002,

); //restricted values. they can come from anywhere
    if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) { 
         return false;

    }   

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        /* Edited by vikas_mageworx */
        $postcode=$request->getDestPostcode();
        $countrycode=$request->getDestCountry();
        $items=$request->getAllItems();
        /* End Editing by vikas_mageworx */

        $postcode=str_replace('-', '', $postcode);
        $shippingdetail=array();

        /*  one start */
        $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode,'items'=>$items);
       /*  one end  */

         /* tt start - ship charges never work  
         $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode);
         tt end */


        foreach($items as $item) {
            $proid=$item->getProductId();
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                    $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                    if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                        $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $mpassignModel = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $partner = $mpassignModel->getSellerId();
            } else {
                $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$proid));
                foreach($collection as $temp) {
                    $partner=$temp->getUserid();
                }
            }

            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid)->getWeight();
            $weight=$product*$item->getQty();
            if(count($shippingdetail)==0){
                array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
            }else{
                $shipinfoflag=true;
                $index=0;
                foreach($shippingdetail as $itemship){
                    if($itemship['seller_id']==$partner){
                        $itemship['items_weight']=$itemship['items_weight']+$weight;
                        $itemship['product_name']=$itemship['product_name'].",".$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id']=$itemship['item_id'].",".$item->getId();
                        $itemship['qty']=$itemship['qty']+$item->getQty();
                        $shippingdetail[$index]=$itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag=false;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
                if($shipinfoflag==true){
                    array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
                }
            }
        }
        $shippingpricedetail=$this->getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail);

        if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
            return $result;
        }
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $shippingAll=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('shippinginfo');
        $shippingAll[$this->_code]=$shippingpricedetail['shippinginfo'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('shippinginfo',$shippingAll);

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/name'));
        $method->setCost($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']);
        $method->setPrice($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']); 
        $result->append($method);
        return $result; 
    }







public function getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail) {
        $shippinginfo=array();
        $handling=0;
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $customerAddress = $session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();


/* Edited by vikas_boy */
$customerPostCode = $shippostaldetail['postalcode'];
$items = $shippostaldetail['items'];
 /* End Editing by vikas_boy  */




 /* one  */

        foreach($shippingdetail as $shipdetail) {
            $seller = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($shipdetail['seller_id']);
            $sellerAddress = $seller->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            $distance = $this->getDistanse($sellerAddress->getPostcode(),$customerPostCode);
            // echo "distance ".$distance;die;
            $price = 0;
            $itemsarray=explode(',',$shipdetail['item_id']);
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $proid=$item->getProductId();
                $options=$item->getProductOptions();
                $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
                if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                    foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                        $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                        if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                            $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($proid))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $mpshippingcharge = 0;
                $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
                $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
                $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
                if(in_array($item->getId(),$itemsarray)) {
                    if($mpassignproductId) {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getStateShippingCharge();
                        }
                    } else {
                         // echo "imte ".$item->getProductId();
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpLocalShippingCharge();
                            // echo "imte ".$item->getProductId();
                            // echo "ship ".$mpshippingcharge;
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpStateShippingCharge();
                        }   
                    }

                    /* tt */
                    // echo "test ".$mpshippingcharge;die;
                    if(!is_numeric($mpshippingcharge)){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount')* floatval($item->getQty()));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+($mpshippingcharge * floatval($item->getQty()));
                    }
                    /* tt end */

                    /* one
                    if(floatval($mpshippingcharge)==0){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount'));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+$mpshippingcharge;
                    }
                      one end */
                }
            }

            $handling = $handling+$price;
            $submethod = array(array('method'=>Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'),'cost'=>$price,'error'=>0));
            array_push($shippinginfo,array('seller_id'=>$shipdetail['seller_id'],'methodcode'=>$this->_code,'shipping_ammount'=>$price,'product_name'=>$shipdetail['product_name'],'submethod'=>$submethod,'item_ids'=>$shipdetail['item_id']));
        }
        $msg="";
        return array('handlingfee'=>$handling,'shippinginfo'=>$shippinginfo,'errormsg'=>$msg);
    }


 /* one end */

    /* tt start */

    private function getDistanse($origin,$destination) {
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$origin.",india&destinations=".$destination.",india&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response_all = json_decode($response);
        $distance = $response_all->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value / 1000;
        if($distance==0){
            $zips = array(
                $origin,$destination
                // ... etc ...
            );

            $geocoded = array();
            $serviceUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:%s&sensor=false";
            $curl = curl_init();
            foreach ($zips as $zip) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, sprintf($serviceUrl, urlencode($zip)));
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                $data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
                $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                if ($info['http_code'] != 200) {
                    // Request failed
                } else if ($data->status !== 'OK') {
                    // Something happened, or there are no results
                } else {
                    $geocoded[$zip] =$data->results[0]->geometry->location;
                }
            }
            $distance=$this->DistAB($geocoded[$zips[0]]->lat,$geocoded[$zips[0]]->lng,$geocoded[$zips[1]]->lat,$geocoded[$zips[1]]->lng);

            }
        return $distance;
    }

    /* tt end * /






/* tt start  */

public function DistAB($lat_a,$lon_a,$lat_b,$lon_b)

      { 

        $measure_unit = 'kilometers';

        $measure_state = false;

        $measure = 0;

        $error = '';

          $delta_lat = $lat_b - $lat_a ;
          $delta_lon = $lon_b - $lon_a ;
          $earth_radius = 6372.795477598;

          $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
          $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
          $a        = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($this->lat_a)) * cos(deg2rad($this->lat_b)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
          $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
          $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
          $distance = round($distance, 4);

         $measure = $distance;
         return $measure;

      }

    }
```

Comment: The code your showing us isn't where the error is from. Show us the code in var/www/html/vikas/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php